# Set camera iso on Nexus 4

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

When i use `camParams.set("iso", (String)newValue);` in my app and run it on my Nexus 4, the preview gets really slow and after awhile it crash because of high memory use.

when i use `cameraParameters.set("iso", 100);` the preview is very slow but when i use `cameraParameters.set("iso", 1600);` it works perfectly.

It also happens in other camera apps like FV-5 when you change the iso setting.

on Samsung Galaxy S 2 it works perfectly. what can i do?

Comment: Since that's undocumented, why are you expecting it to have an effect, let alone a positive one?